# How to make sqlplus output appear in one line?

Tags: linux, set, output, sqlplus

```
   set serveroutput on size 100000

   set serveroutput off
   set termout off
   set newpage 0
   set echo off
   set linesize 32767
   set pagesize 0
   set feedback off
   set heading off
   set trimspool on
   set verify off

   SPOOL $UDATEFILE
   @rocks_update.sql $BeginDate
   SPOOL OFF

   SPOOL $IRTFILE
   @rocks_insert.sql $BeginDate 
   SPOOL OFF
```

This is my set but I'm not getting each record in one row.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
select client_id||' '||first_name||' '||last_name from clients;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple as it looks just give the size limit when you're creating a new table. Example:

```
create table test (name varchar(255));
```

This will create blankspaces in the output console. Create it as much for the requirements. Example:

```
create table test ( name char(15) );
```